# Unable to boot on Debian Live CD on my HP Laptop - "Selected boot image did not authenticate"

Tags: boot, debian, uefi

I'm trying to boot from a Debian Live CD (the *debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso* available here: http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.5.0/amd64/bt-dvd/).

It doesn't work when I just let the computer start (the boot order is correct and worked for Ubuntu Mate Live CD).

I'm getting the following error message when I try to boot from the BIOS menu :     **Selected boot image did not authenticate**.

I read on HP forum that I should enable Legacy Boot Mode and disable Secure Boot. I did that, but each time I go back to the BIOS menu, the Legacy Boot Mode is disabled again and the Secure Boot is enabled again (though I correctly used "Save & Exit").

I'm a bit at loss, any help? I'm using an HP Pavilion.

Comment: What is the intalled OS on your PC?

Comment: It's Windows 10

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem while trying to install Debian Jessie from USB on my new HP laptop that came with Windows 10.
I fixed it by disabling Secure Boot and enabling Legacy Boot Mode in the BIOS and saving just as you did.

However, upon reboot I got a message saying "There is a boot mode change pending, press Esc if you do not want these changes to take effect or type in the given password+Enter to apply the changes"

Please note that repeatedly pressing Esc may cancel that prompt and prevent Legacy mode from being implemented so be patient, I had to do that twice before I could get it.
After that everything worked out smoothly

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the `fast-startup` from windows settings:

> Fast startup (aka: hiberboot, hybrid boot, or hybrid shutdown) is turned on by default in Windows and is a setting that helps your PC start up faster after shutdown. Even faster than hibernate. Windows does this by saving an image of the Windows kernel and loaded drivers to the hiberfile (C:\hiberfil.sys) upon shutdown so when you start your PC again, Windows simply loads the hiberfile (C:\hiberfil.sys) into memory to resume your PC instead of restarting it.

If the `fast-startup` is activated Windows will load the `hiberfile` file and disallow to boot on Linux CDs

[How to Turn On or Off Fast Startup in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)